# Understanding quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, string-theory, wave-particle-duality

Forgive me for this dumb question but what are matter waves of particles?
are they particles being spread out in a space like waves or the particles are still "particles" but matter waves are probability waves?
and if the particle is actually spread out in space like a wave then why does this page from wikipedia about string theory says that strings replace "point-like particles"?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantum mechanics is applicable in the regime of extremely small (when length scale ~ $h/p$). So lets talk about small particles. For such particles, something strange happens:

1. when they are detected they behave as if they are particles in the conventional sense: that is they have an exact value for their energy and momenta. Imagine it this way: when the particle's position is detected say at a screen of some detector, its hits it at just one tiny spot.
2. strangely, if the detection experiment were to be repeated, the energy momentum values are found to be different. They are nevertheless exact this time too.

(by repeated, we mean detection performed by an ensemble of identically prepared systems)

Therefore, there is a probability distribution associated with the energy-momentum of the particle. This is true for any observable. When the observable is position, the associated probability density is called a matter wave.

The matter wave is unlike any notion of wave that you may have. It is *not*

1. matter of the particle smeared out in space in the form a standing or propagating wave
2. a wave in the probability distribution of the observable
3. a wave in the form of which the original particle travels.

All a particle's associated matter wave represents is the probability of detection of that particle at different points in space. At every detection, the particle exhibits particulate properties. This is the particle nature. However since it doesn't seem to be able decide upon one value of its position, its as if its spread out. This is the wave nature. This is wave-matter duality.

Why can't we say the particle is actually spread out like a wave i.e it travels like a wave? Because it is not experimentally possible to detect the form in which a particle travels-to do so requires detection and at the moment of detection, each particle appears particulate in nature.

What is the wave in the "matter wave"? I am not completely sure. The particle's wave functions (whose mod square gives he probability density) is in general imaginary though it does sometimes appear as if its spreading in space or moving in space with time.. like a pulse expanding. But its nothing like what you associate waves with--sound, water eaves, EM fields etc.

Comment: -1: _"[W]hen they are detected they behave as if they are particles in the conventional sense: that is they have an exact value for their energy and momenta. Imagine it this way: when the particle is detected say at a screen of some detector, its hits at just one tiny spot."_ This is wrong in multiple ways: 1. Whether a particle can be measured to have an exact value for their energy and momenta depends on the Hamiltonian. If the Hamiltonian doesn't commute with the momentum operators, you can't measure both energy and momenta at the same time. [...]

Comment: [...] 2. Whether a particle will have a precise momentum or not when you "detect" the particle depends entirely on your mechanism of detecting. If you are measuring the momentum then it would have a precise momentum, if you are measuring the position, it would have a precise position. Both are legitimate ways of detection. 3. A way to think about a particle measured to have a precise momentum is not to imagine it having a localized position like hitting at just one tiny spot. It is the opposite. A particle with a definite momentum would not have a precise position at all.

Comment: Probability density is a real, not imaginary, quantity. Matter waves are complex waves of probability *amplitude* whose modulus squared is the probability density.

Comment: @DvijMankad For your point 3, doesn't applying that reasoning only apply for the distribution of measurements of similarly prepared quantum systems?  i.e. if we obtain a smaller spread in momentum measurements we would expect a larger spread in position measurements?

Comment: @G Smith. Thank you. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: @DvijMankad Thank you for your input. 1. If one were to do a simultaneous measurement of non commutating observables, for every single measurement, each observable must have some exact value. The associated heisenberg uncertainty comes from the average over ensemble. So if the $[E,p]\ne=0$, and say the particle was in its energy eigenstate, all msr. would report same value for energy but incredibly different values for momenta--to the extent that one concludes that the particle doesn't have a well defined momenta at all  at  each msr p is defined.

Comment: @DvijMankad 3. same with x,p. At each msr. x is definite. For particles with no uncertainity in p, the incredible lack of localization would become apparent across the ensemble.

Comment: @DvijMankad 2. what i am trying to say is each measurement always detects the object to be "particulate in nature" regardless of what its measuring. In every measurement, the observables take a stand. During a position measurement, there is only one position where the particle is detected.  If it were inherently wave like, it would simultaneously be detected at different places.  Also since such this measurement is not concerned with p, nobody knows whether that is definite or not. I just chose $E$,$p$ as the apt properties to measure if something were particulate.